# Npgsql 42601: date format not recognized

Tags: npgsql

I am currently getting a date format not recognized error when trying to fetch from a refcursor. The query used in pgAdmin for both the function call and fetch match exactly with the call coming from the .NET code and yet only the .NET code is throwing this error. The result set only consists of character_varying and numeric. Currently using .NET 6 with Npgsql 6.0.3.

```
                await using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var tran = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync();
                await using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection)
                {
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
                    Transaction = tran
                })
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("refCursor", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor, 10, "refCursor",
                        System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, false, 2, 2, System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, null));

                    command.Prepare();
                    var cursorName = "";
                    await using (var portal = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {

                        while (portal.Read())
                        {
                            cursorName = portal[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    command.CommandText = $"fetch all in \"{cursorName}\"";
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                    await using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
```

The exception points to: File: char_todatetime.c Routine: execute_char_todatetime_format. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's best to post a fully runnable code sample, including the database schema.

Comment: The query is a function call with a lot of different parts to it (was not written by me) but in the end, the result only consists of character varying and numeric. If the database schema or query was the issue, wouldn't it also not work when running it in pgAdmin's query tool?

Comment: It's impossible to know what's going on without more detail - we don't even have the SQL query above (or the db schema). I'd try to reproduce this in an isolated code sample, there's also a good chance you'll find the issue while doing that.